# Displaying user daya after google login ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

After couple hours making this app, i'm stuck with google login, i've ask question before but still stuck.

so i have logic.service.ts which handle user to login and get their data store them in localStorage

```
login(){
    this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId' : '927898787134-spvfdmvm9apq0e1fo2efvvura8vqpid8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offile' : true
    }).then(res=>{
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
      .then(suc=>{
        // console.log('users', JSON.stringify(suc));
        this.storage.set('user', JSON.stringify(suc));
        this.router.navigate(["/tabs/home"]);
      }).catch(ns=>{
        alert('Unsucessful');
      })
    })
  }
```

and then i try to get user data and display it on other page, but i'm stuck because i don't get things that i needed. in my home.page.ts

```
     userData:any;
  loginDetails:any;
  subscribe: any;
  user:any={};
  public items: any;
  constructor(
    private iab: InAppBrowser,
    private router: Router,
    public platform: Platform,
    private service: LogicService,
    private nativeStorage: NativeStorage
    ) {

    this.subscribe = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(666666, () => {
      if (this.constructor.name === 'HomePage') {
        if (window.confirm('Do you want to exit the app?')) {
          (navigator as any).app.exitApp();
        }
      }
    });
    let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    console.log(userData.user);
    console.log(userData.user.displayName);
    console.log(userData.user.email);
    console.log(userData.user.photoURL);
  }
  go() {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/login');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getLocalData().subscribe(
      data => {this.items = data});
  }
  webview(url){
    this.iab.create(url, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no');
  }
```

i call the data and parse it into object, when i call console.log(user) it shows me this

[image]

but when i try to call user.displayName it says undifined

[image: undefined]

after updated my code, i'm able to log my data but i'm trying to display it on html like this

```
<div class="header">
          <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{ userData.user.displayName }}</h3>
          <p style="color:grey;font-weight:bold;">Get closer with us!</p>
        </div>
```

but now i get an error like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the incorrect object, instead use:

```
let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log(userData.user.displayName);
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments you need to define `userData` as a class level so that it is visible in your template (make sure you don't redefine it in the constructor as it will then *hide* the class-level variable).

Comment: oh i see, but how to display it on html? i got an error if i call {{ userData.user.displayName }}

Comment: 1. What is the error? 2. Were you able to get the desired output in the console with the above answer?

Comment: userData is not defined, yeah i get what i wanted on console, but still stuck on showing it on html

Comment: <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{ userData.user.displayName }}</h3>

Comment: Make sure the *scope* of `userData` is not restricted to a method i.e it should be defined as a class-level variable.

Comment: i don't understand that sorry, what should i do exactly?

Comment: How/Where have you defined `userData`?

Comment: i defined userData outside the constructor, i'll try to run it again

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined then it shows that error

Comment: Without seeing what *exactly* you are trying I can't really guess the issue..

Comment: i'll provide you in my question wait

Comment: Share the component code where you are setting the value for `userData`

Comment: Are those lines wrapped in a method? They can't be dangling around in the class.

Comment: Please update your question with *all appropriate* code and not snippets of them which 'feel' relevant.

Comment: i updated it again, i copy all code from my home.page.ts

Comment: Replace this line `let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));` **with** `this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));` and remove the subsequent console.log

Comment: The issue is that your the `userData` defined within the constructor is *hiding* the class level variable. I suggest you go through basics of OOPS before diving head first into frameworks like Angular, etc.

Comment: wow you're the man, it works! yeah i realize that, i just started using angular and ionic about 1 month ago so i'm still newbie, sorry my bad, but thanks anyway, it's been 12 hours just to get that value LOL